# Slow printing on Ricoh MP C2003 / Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printer

I do not have any other computer to print from, but my Windows 10 desktop prints very slow.

PDF's and this current powerpoint (color, about 8meg in size) is taking at least 10 minutes to print.

Comment: How many pages to the file? You say "color, about 8meg in size". If the file has the same picture on every page (common in PPT) then it is stored only once, but needs to be sent to the printer for every page, so printer output can be MUCH larger than the file size. Check the size of the spool file (double-click the little printer icon in the Taskbar).

Comment: The spool size is about 8mb when I printed that PPT for example... anything I can do to speed up the printing?

Comment: Try resetting the printer to factory defaults. See http://www.ehow.com/how_6767608_reset-ricoh-factory-settings.html . You can also completely remove (delete printer and remove driver via Print Server Properties) and reinstall the driver.